# not able to get refs on addEventListener callback function

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, addeventlistener

I have a custom component which listen for an event and if detected call the callback function.

```
componentWillMount(props){
        this.setState(this.props);
        window.removeEventListener("ReactGridItemResize",this.onReactGridItemResize.bind(this));
        window.addEventListener("ReactGridItemResize",this.onReactGridItemResize.bind(this),false);
    }

onReactGridItemResize(){
        this.refs.highChart.chart.reflow();
    }
```

in `render` method I am setting the `ref` like this

```
<div className="chart pull-right">
                        <ReactHighcharts ref="highChart" config={chartConfig}/>
                      </div>
```

if I try to access the same `ref` on `componentDidMount` I am able to access that not sure why It is not able to get the same on `addEventListener` callback because this callback will be fired based on some user action which will be definitely trigger after `componentDidMount`.

so `this.refs.highChart` is coming as `null`.

Please help me out on this.

Thanks.

Comment: can you add some small jsFiddle showing your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try a callback as a value of the `ref` prop like so:

```
<div className="chart pull-right">
  <ReactHighcharts ref={ chart => { this.highChart = chart; } } config={chartConfig}/>
</div>
```

And then in the handler:

```
this.highChart.chart.reflow();
```